# OpenSSL canonicalization

Tags: openssl, ws-security

Question:  does openssl have the ability to do a C14N (canonicalization) transform on, for example, a soap message?  In particular I need to transform the body section AND the SignedInfo section of a soap message before I use openssl to sign.

I can't find anything searching the online docs that would indicate openssl can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather use a XML security library - which OpenSSL **is not**. XML security libraries should all support XML canonicalization as far as I know. Examples: Apache Santuario for Java and C++, XMLSec Library for C, etc. Apache Santuario uses OpenSSL as underlying crypto library by default.

If you play with SOAP message signing/encryption extensively, you should seriously consider using a WS-Security framework.